# Tables are logical structures or they exist physically?

Tags: database, relational-database

While reading a book on databases I came across this paragraph

The **relational model** is based on the mathematical concept of a relation, which is
***physically*** represented as a table. Codd, a trained mathematician, used terminology
taken from mathematics, principally set theory and predicate logic.

Is he right to say that a relation is physically represented as a table? We know that tables are logical structures, they are just abstractions on the actual data structure used to store data.

Any explcanations would be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Physical" tends to be used to describe any underlying technology, implementation mechanism or means of representation. "Logical" tends to be used to describe data structures that can be represented or implemented in different ways in terms of other data structures or computer memory. From the point of view of relations, tables are considered physical since they can be used to represent relations.

The term "logical" has another meaning when applied to database relations. They're not just logical in the abstract sense above, but also in the mathematical sense, being used to represent predicates and propositions, and manipulated via relational algebra/calculus which are equivalent to first-order logic.

The other term you'll encounter in this context is "conceptual". This refers to models that mirror the ontological structure of a domain, like entity-relationship models.

Comment: So logical means the logical structures used to représent data ie the data structures , that's what I'm saying tables are some kind of data structure it's not a physical . It's really confusing .